# webpack build everything into subfolder except the index.html

Tags: javascript, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I have this structure

```
index.html
src/img/image.png
src/js/app.js
src/fonts/font.ttf
src/css/styles.css
```

For my distribution I would like to build everything into a folder except the html file something like this:

```
dist/index.html
dist/assets/styles.css
dist/assets/app.js
dist/assets/font.ttf
.....
```

This is what I'm trying right now but it seems webpack still builds everything inside the assets folder including the index.html

```
output: {
path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/Assets'),
filename: '[name].[hash].bundle.js'
},

plugins:[   
 new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: 'src/index.html',
  chunksSortMode: 'dependency',
  filename: path.resolve(__dirname, './index.html'),
}),
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the second argument to `'../index.html'`.

```
 new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: 'src/index.html',
  chunksSortMode: 'dependency',
  filename: path.resolve(__dirname, '../index.html'),
}),
```